# How to create element in another model with django

Tags: python, django

I have a small question. That is actually making me scratch my head.
So in my Database, I have the following models:

- Activity
- Bill
- Clients

I think you are all seeing the relationship I am trying to create :

A Bill has one client and one or more activities. Here is the trick to make this whole thing user-friendly I am trying to create Bills (with the url: Bill/new) that can be edited manually. So the user is sent to an HTML page with the basic Bill template and he has a table that can add some rows with the activity the time spent and its cost.

There are three things I am trying to achieve.

1. Generate automatically the ID of the Bill (it should be pk of Bill) but it seems it's not generated until I have pressed on save.
2. When I save a Bill I want to save also the activities I have entered manually.
3. When I save the Bill I would like to save it as a Word or PDF document in the database.

Are these possible?

Thanks all for reading and helping I am banging my head to figure out how to do all of this and I am quite a newbie so any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be for the Bill objects to have a boolean field `in_preparation`. There would be a sequence of forms involved. The first would create a minimal Bill object with `in_preparation=True`. Then the related objects could be created and linked to this Bill. The final stage would be to display the entire bill and related objects for checking, with options to go back and edit, or "Confirm and issue to customer". This latter would set `in_preparation=False` and generate the pdf and word files.

If all the necessary information is already available and you are just asking how to use a ModelForm in this circumstance, the answer is `obj = form.save( commit=False)`. It's then up to you to call `obj.save()` once you have finished updating it or its related objects [More information here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

If you are saving a bunch of objects at once and want to be sure it's all-or-nothing (the latter if something throws an exception), you need a Django transaction.

Answer (score 0):

> Generate automatically the ID of the Bill (it should be pk of Bill) but it seems it's not generated until I have pressed on save.

For bills and any other "real world"-like documents you'd probably better define some custom number generator to detach number from the auto-id and to be able to generate numbers using more complex patterns (eg AB-12345/321).

But in any case whether you choose to use auto-id or a custom generator the most simple way to garanty existence and uniqueness of that id/number is to save bill instance first. Also this approach has some additional pros.

> When I save a Bill I want to save also the activities I have entered manually.

You can use django formsets for this (assuming that your bill and activity models have fk or m2m relation)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/

> When I save the Bill I would like to save it as a Word or PDF document in the database.

I'm not really sure if it is a good idea to store pdf or word files in db somehow.

In my opinion there are better ways

1. Generate pdf (word, excel etc) docs from data on request
2. Store as files in filesystem.

   In this case files shouldn't be stored in publicly accessible
   dirs (like media and static) and should be served instead with
   FileResponce with proper access checks in the view